# Raising builtin exception with default message in python

Tags: python, exception

I'm trying to implement a method that returns an error whenever a certain directory does not exist.

Rather than doing `raise OSError("Directory does not exist.")`, however, I want to use the builtint error message from OSError: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`. This is because I am raising the exception in the beginning of the method call, rather than later (which would invoke the same message from python, without any necessary `raise`).

Any pointers? (other than manually doing `OSError("[Errno 2] No such file or directory: ")`)

Comment: Trigger the exception and let it propagate?

Comment: Why don't you want to raise the exception yourself at the beginning of your method call, e.g. with `raise OSError(...)`?  It's a perfectly valid way of telling your caller that there is a problem.

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do ~ I was just looking for a way to access the built-in error messages.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
import os

try:
    open('foo')
except IOError as err:
    print(err)
    print(err.args)
    print(err.filename)
```

produces

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foo'
(2, 'No such file or directory')
foo
```

So, to generate an `OSError` with a similar message use

```
raise OSError(2, 'No such file or directory', 'foo')
```

Comment: Using the error names from the `errno` module and `os.strerror` to translate them to a localized message string is preferable to hard-coded values: `OSError(errno.ENOENT, os.strerror(errno.ENOENT), filename)`

Comment: Use **e.errno, e.filename, and e.strerror** to get information about the exception. Note it looks like these are all None (including errno) unless at least two args are specified to the exception, with filename being the third argument.

Answer (score 12):

To get the error message for a given error code, you might want to use [`os.strerror`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.strerror):

```
>>> os.strerror(2)
'No such file or directory'
```

Also, you might want to use [`errno`](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html) module to use the standard abbreviations for those errors:

```
>>> errno.ENOENT
2
>>> os.strerror(errno.ENOENT)
'No such file or directory'
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this. This will be useful :). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think that "exception" is the Python language term for what you are calling "error". So use this term as you search for more information.

You might find it useful to read the [Python Standard Library documentation, "6. Built-in Exceptions"](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IOError).

[`OSError`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OSError) is one of the built-in exceptions. It's defined in the "Built-in Exceptions" section, which adds, "The `errno` attribute is a numeric error code from errno, and the `strerror` attribute is the corresponding string, as would be printed by the C function `perror()`. See the module [`errno`](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html#module-errno), which contains names for the error codes defined by the underlying operating system."

Running this code:

```
raise OSError(42, "my exception string", "no_such_file.dat")
```

gives me this result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Line 1, in <module>
    raise OSError(42, "my exception string", "no_such_file.dat")
OSError: [Errno 42] my exception string: 'no_such_file.dat'
```

So, I think your code could do something like:

```
raise OSError(2, "No such file or directory", filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the real problem here is that you are probably doing a bunch of checks beforehand instead of just trying.

```
try:
    [CODE]
except Exception:
    [HANDLING CODE]
```

is much better than:

```
if [SPECIAL CASE]:
    [HANDLING CODE]
elif [special case]:
    [SPECIAL CASE]
[CODE]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try:
    # ...
except OSError:
    raise OSError("your answer")
```

Comment: sorry for such view, i post answer from android and it has no normal code edit